$m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. $m<n\implies m\subset n$.
I am reading Logic in mathematics and set theory by Kazuyuki Tanaka and Toshio Suzuki.

Lemma 2.5:
For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, each element of the set $n$ belongs to $\mathbb{N}$.


Definition 2.3:
$m,n\in\mathbb{N}$.
$m<n$ if and only if $m\in n$.


Theorem 2.6:
$l,m,n\in\mathbb{N}$.
If $l<m$ and $m<n$, then $l<n$.


Corollary 2.7:
$m,n\in\mathbb{N}$.
$m<n\implies m\subset n$.


Proof of Corollary 2.7 by the authors:
It is obvious by Lemma 2.5 and Theorem 2.6.

How to use Lemma 2.5 and Theorem 2.6 to prove Corollary 2.7?
The following is my proof:

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$.
If $n=0$, then $m<n$ does not hold.
So, $m<n\implies m\subset n$ holds.
Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Suppose $m<n\implies m\subset n$ holds.
If $m<n\cup\{n\}$, then this means $m\in n\cup\{n\}$.
If $m\in n$, then this means $m<n$.
By inductive hypothesis, $m\subset n$.
And $n\subset n\cup\{n\}$.
So, $m\subset n\cup\{n\}$.
If $m\in\{n\}$, then $m=n$.
Then, $m=n\subset n\cup\{n\}$.
So, by induction, Corollary 2.7 holds.


What in Definition 2.3 is getting defined?

If I'm not wrong, there is no need for induction and you can do it much simpler like this: let m<n, then:
$$\ell\in m \iff \ell<m$$
Then, if $\ell\in m$, we have $\ell<m$ and $m<n\implies \ell<n$, and $\ell<n\iff \ell\in n$. So we conclude that $\ell\in m\implies \ell\in n$, so $m\subset n$.

Where/how did you use Lemma 2.5? I don't see it.

I used it because I applied Theorem 2.6 to $\ell,m,n$, so it must be that since $\ell\in m$, by Lemma 2.5 $\ell\in\mathbb N$, if not I cannot apply Theorem 2.6.

You have not shown that $m$ is a proper subset of $n$. This is where you need the induction. If we have the result $n \notin n$, then we can use this to show the proper subset. Otherwise to show $n \notin n$ we need induction.

Yes, I think by the definition $m\notin m$ because it is not true that $m<m$; then we conclude that $m\in n$ which we have because $m<n$ and we are done.
